# Call a js function from .json file

Tags: javascript, json, function

I want to execute a function from the JSON file I have,
How can I do it?

can I just do it like that:

```
// JSON file
{
exJsFunction();
}
```

or is there even a way to write the function here?

Comment: Can you explain your use case? Why would you want to do it like this?

Comment: JSON is only a data interchange format. It cannot be used as a source of runtime executable statements in JavaScript engines which follow the spec. Can you explain with more detail what you are trying to accomplish? See [ask].

Comment: I'm writing automation tests and in the testing tool I'm using,  each test I write starts with a JSON file called test-data, I can't run a function before the test but I'd like to set the function inside the 'test-data' file, so I would get my return data before the test starts

Comment: The answer is No. you cannot.

Answer (score 0):

You could check your json in order to get an identifier, if exists, call the function. This solution creates dependency between js code and json, but it's a way I can think of to be able to do it.

I've made a simply example:

```js
var jsonData = {"widget": {
    "debug": "on",
    "window": {
        "title": "Sample Konfabulator Widget",
        "name": "main_window",
        "width": 500,
        "height": 500
    }
}};

function showMessage(){

    var output2 = document.getElementById("output2");
  output2.innerHTML = "Function executed";

}

var output = document.getElementById("output");
output.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(jsonData) + '<br /><br />';


if(jsonData.widget.window.name === "main_window") {

    showMessage();

}
```

```html
<span id="output"></span>
<br /><br />
<span id="output2">output 2</span>
```